# Is it possible to install latest Github software releases through apt-get on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, github

I usually install software through apt-get on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install the latest stable version (v8.6.5) of this software:
https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/releases

The problem is that if I were to install through apt-get, I would end up with version 8.4.5-1build1

Is there a way for me to install this latest version v8.6.5 through apt-get?  Or am I forced to download/compile myself, then track down all the dependencies?  What is the best way to handle my situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a .deb package yourself, then you can use apt for installing it. This process contains the compiling, of course.
https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Answer (score 0):

I found no repositories that offered the latest version as of this writing (8.6.5) of vips. I did however find this blog post which covers very well the steps to create your own DEB package.

- [How to build up-to-date VIPS packages for Debian](https://renchap.com/blog/post/building_recent_libvips_on_debian/)

#### General steps

**NOTE:** Consult the above, there may be some bits not covered below. Below shows the ***general*** steps to do what you're asking, given there's no official repo that provides these.

*setup build env & download vips*

```
$ apt install build-essential devscripts

$ curl -LO https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/releases/download/v8.6.5/vips-8.6.5.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf <tarball>
$ cd <unpacked tarball dir>
$ curl -LO http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vips/vips_8.6.5.orig.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf <tarball>
```

*install deps*

```
$ mk-build-deps
$ sudo apt install ./vips-build-deps_*.deb
```

*build*

```
$ debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

Results

```
$ sudo apt install *.deb
```